# Composite C1 rendering � randomly for Japanese

Tags: html, c1-cms

I have a site that has English, German, and Japanese content served from 3 different domains out of the same IIS site and same Composite C1 CMS.  The Japanese content has an issue where some characters, not always the same one, are displaying as � on the page for the end user.  It renders fine in the CMS even when broken on the page.  I have found a temp fix by placing span tags around the Japanese character in the CMS when I find them.  However others show up later, and does not seem to fix it every time.  I cannot figure out what the cause is.  Has anyone had something similar occur to them, even if on a different CMS?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running Composite C1 version 3.2 (Patch 1 or 2) - install patch 3 you should be fine. Or upgrade to a later version.

See http://community.composite.net/Blog/2012/10/25/Patch-3-available-for-Composite-C1-32 for info about this issue and how you install the patch.

Comment: Actually we are running version 4.0 Beta.  That should include the patch that you are talking about.  If 4.0 is out of Beta maybe I should try that.  Thanks

Comment: Upgrade to the final release (see "Upgrading from 4.0 Beta" on https://compositec1.codeplex.com/releases/view/107254 ) 

The patches mentioned were produced during the development of the 4.0 release and it is very likely that your beta has the same issue - and that upgrading to the RTM version will fix your issue.

Comment: I tried to upgrade and got this error:   Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Mail support (at) composite (dot) net with exception info. Premium support is free for beta users upgrading to final releases. Mention what version you are upgrading from / to.